# How to add attribute to client in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to store a string in the client context (same like user attribute) so that I can retrieve it using client REST API but i want to store it via console. How can i add this new field in client?

Comment: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/add-field-in-client-settings/7861

Comment: @JanGaraj I want to add this string via console so that anyone with credentials can add value.

Comment: I already told you on the Keycloak forum, so I'm repeating: customize `client-detail.html` template

Comment: @JanGaraj sorry for that, but actually i'm trying to avoid customizing the `client-detail.html` template and finding other way if possible. Thank you i will customize the template.

Answer (score 0):

By customizing the `client-detail.html` template

https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/add-field-in-client-settings/7861